# Loopback where filter on an array type field

Tags: arrays, filter, where-clause, contains, loopback

I'm working on a loopback project, I have a model called Depot which has a field `likersList`, that fiels is an array of string (`user id`)
I want to find all  `Depots` which has not a specific `userId` in it's `likersList` , I tried that filter, but it doesn't work

```
let userId=req.accessToken.userId;
let filter={
   where:{
       and:[
           ....
           {likersList:{nin:[userId]}}
       ]
   }
   ....
}
```

I also try that `{likerList:{neq:userId}}` , doesn't work too
But if try this `likersList:userId` that returns all `Depots` which has `userId`in it's likersList , so I expected that doing `{likerList:{neq:userId}}` sould do a opposite

All I want is to know how to check if a field (array type) contains a certain value

Help please !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works here:

It brings all objects that **dont** contains userId inside the likersList.

```
let filter={
    where: {
        {
            likersList: {neq: userId}
        }
    }
}
```

It brings **only** objects that **contains** userId inside the likersList.

```
let filter={
    where: {
        {
            likersList: userId
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What database are you using for your loopback application? I have seen scenarios where `nin` and `inq` filter doesn't work for Oracle database. I have used appropriate regular expression filter as a workaround.

Comment: I use mongodb , but i think the problem comes from the `near` filter I use in the where clause, once I get off the near in the `and` array in the `where` data all function normaly  

Thank you for you reply , I  try an other alternative

Comment: abskmj which regular expression have you used? can you please let me know? I am facing similar issue with postgres DB.

Comment: @ShubhiSood Sorry, I don't have a reference to the code base anymore.